# "Promise nothing" motto for a coat of arms

Tags: translation-check, motto

I'm looking for a motto for a coat of arms which would be an impersonal sentence (as it should be in a coat of arms) and read something like "Never promise anything" or "Promise nothing". Right now I'm considering

> Nihil promittere

Is this correct? Are there any other more suitable expressions?

Comment: Do you want it to be the infinitive "to promise", an order "promise", a participle "the one(s) who promise", or perhaps a "we promise"? I guess the infinitive is the best choice for impersonality, but it'd be good to know if you have an opinion. I can elaborate in an answer later, but now I have some Thanksgiving to attend to.

Comment: I think it should be infinitive. Though I'd like to compare. :D

Comment: This brings to mind the Greek maxim which was written on the Temple of Apollo at Delphi: Ἐγγύα πάρα δ'ἄτη. (Make a promise, and destruction is nearby.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *nihil promittere* is correct, but let me explore some alternatives.

There are a number of choices to make.
The first one is choosing a verb.
The options that come to mind are [*polliceri*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=polliceor&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), [*promittere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=promitto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), and [*spondere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=spondeo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
Your choice *promittere* has the issue of having several different meanings, and it can be misconstrued in a motto.
It seems to me that *spondere* is for more solemn promises than *polliceri*, and perhaps a coat of arms calls for some amount of solemnity.
I would therefore suggest *spondere*, but the choice is yours.
Check the links for details on these three verbs, or check any resource on [our list of online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) for more options.

I chose to use *numquam* ("never"), but you can easily replace it with *nihil* ("nothing") if you prefer.
Also combinations are possible; ask for details if something specific sounds interesting.

The last choice is choosing a structure.
Using *spondere*, I might suggest one of these:

1. *Numquam spondere*
   To never promise
2. *Numquam spondens/spondentes*
   One/Ones who never promises/promise
   (This is really a participle, so the translation is not entirely accurate.)
3. *Numquam spondemus*
   We never promise
4. *Numquam spondeto*
   Never promise (as an order)

The first one might be most suitable, but I find the second one attractive as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive analysis! I think I will go with *Numquam spondens* as it seems to be the closest both grammatically and lexically to what I originally meant.

Comment: @Taosique I'm glad to be of service! *Numquam spondens* sounds good for a coat of arms.

Comment: A bit late for clarification, but does *Nihil umquam spondens* construction make sense?

Comment: @Taosique It does. *Nihil umquam* means "nothing ever", and it's perfectly fine if you want the added emphasis.